# J2EE primesfaces autocomplete value retrieve

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, autocomplete

how to retrieve the selected value of a primefaces autocomplete

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{completeBean.selected1}"  
 id="basicPojo1" completeMethod="#{completeBean.completePlayer}"
 var="p" itemLabel="#{p.getMateriel().getNumparc()}" itemValue="#{p}" 
 converter="numparc" forceSelection="true"> 
    <f:ajax   execute="basicPojo1" listener="#{evenEdl.submitListener}" render="@all"/>
</p:autoComplete>


public void submitListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    String id = event.getComponent().getId();
    switch (id) { 
        case "basicPojo1":
            String parametre = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                                      .getRequestParameterMap().get("basicPojo1");
            System.out.println("test param"+parametre);
                 break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would you like the to get the selected value? And where exactly did you fail?

Comment: In submitListener method, my listener is working properly and the switch retrieves the ID (box "basicPojo1" -> ok). In it, I will wish to retrieve the selected (In String parameter) value of the autocomplete jsf to perform processing Bean side but I do not succeed with this         String parametre = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                                      .getRequestParameterMap().get("basicPojo1");

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. What do you need to do with the selected value? When you choose a value in the autocomplete then it will be bound to completeBean.selected1 when the form is eventually submitted. Or are you trying to populate something else as soon as the value is selected?

Comment: My completeBean.selected1 is always null and I can not recover anything.

Comment: Take a look in the primefaces showcase :http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteSelect.jsf Is this what you want? Take a close look at the p:ajax

Answer (score 1):

Here an example of p:autocomplete with an Entity converter :

---

**Face :**

```
<p:autoComplete id="autocomplete1" value="#{mBAutoComplete.selectedEntity}" completeMethod="#{mBAutoComplete.complete}"
    forceSelection="true" minQueryLength="3" maxResults="10">
    <p:ajax update="autocomplete1" event="itemSelect" listener="#{mBAutoComplete.updateEntity}" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

---

**Converter :**

```
  @FacesConverter(forClass = Entity.class,value = "entityConveter")
  public class EntityConverter implements Converter {

      public EntityConverter() {

      }

      @Override
      public Entity getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2) {
          // get Entity with WebService, but you can get it with other ways :
          // like calling EJB methods or using a Collection of Entity provided in
          // another managed bean
          return services.getWebService().getEntity(Integer.valueOf(arg2));
      }

      @Override
      public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2) {
          return String.valueOf(((Entity) arg2).getEntityID());
      }
  }
```

---

**ManagedBean :**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mBAutoComplete")
@SessionScoped
public class MBAutoComplete {

    // Entity
    private Entity selectedEntity;

    // Entity Autocomplete
    public List<String> complete(String query) {

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Entity en : this.eqList) {
            if (en.getEntityID().startsWith(query)) {
                results.add(en.getEntityID());
            }
        }

        return results;
   }

    public void updateEntity(SelectEvent e) {
         // Don't forget to check null Object sent by SelectEvent
         this.selectedEntity = (Entity) e.getObject();
    }

    // GETTERS & SETTERS

    public void setSelectedEntity(Entity e) {
         this.selectedEntity = e;
    }

    public Entity getSelectedEntity() {
         return this.selectedEntity();
    }

}
```

---

In this example, you don't need to use FacesContext, just use SelectEvent and the Converter.

Hope this help !